# Provide link to open in different browser

Tags: html, ios, facebook

I have a webapp which is running perfectly well in most browsers, but I'm still trying to work out a few bugs which is preventing it from working correctly in iOS Facebook's in-app browser. Until I've got these sorted, I'd like to provide a message to give users the option to open the link in Safari.

The solution I have for now is to use javascript to detect the browser's user agent ([similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21284282/2548697)), and if it's the Facebook in-app browser, provide a message that the webapp is optimised for Safari and give instructions to copy and paste the link into Safari.

My question is this: is there a way to make a `<a>` tag open in a particular browser? I have seen questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244965/phonegap-opening-external-urls-in-safari) which seem to point to using `target="_system"` for Cordova apps, but is there a method to do this with html only?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The definitive answer: No, this is not possible.

As Andrew M mentioned, some browsers have some methods that do some things similar, but a pure html method to open a link in a generic browser does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do this for Safari (using just HTML, anyway). For other browsers that have custom URL schemes, you could do it. For example, for Chrome you could have your link point to googlechrome://www.website.com.